# Is there a way for a built Vue.js app to read an environment variable defined in Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kubernetes, vuejs2, kubernetes-deployment

So I have a project which builds 3 kubernetes pods connecting to each other, namely `server`, `manager` and `browser`, the browser part is implemented using `Vue.js`, others are using `Python Flask`.

I have a configMap storing the address of their services, which is supposed to be shared by the three:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-config
data:
  SERVER_ADDRESS: http://ai-recommender-service:3518
  MANAGER_ADDRESS: http://manager-service:2354
```

with the `browser`, the deployment part is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: browser-deployment
  labels:
    app: browser
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: browser
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: browser
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: browser
          image: browser:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: MANAGER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-config
                  key: MANAGER_ADDRESS
```

In the Vue.js project `browser`, I have a `.js` file which tries to get the env variable through:

```
const ServiceManagerUrl = process.env.MANAGER_ADDRESS;
```

But this doesn't work.

I know that there are other ways, such as creating a `.env` file with the variable with prefix `VUE_APP_` in the root folder, and then load it using something like `process.env.VUE_APP_MANAGER_ADDRESS`, but are there any ways for Vue.js to directly get the environment variables passed through the Kubernetes deployment (as these are shared by other parts of the system), without having to resort to creating extra files?

--- added ---

`Dockerfile of browser`

```
# build stage
FROM node:14-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Are you creating a static production build for the `browser` container?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Matt

Comment: So environment variables don't really apply to static builds, unless you have some form of app server to pick them up and inject them into the content to be delivered.

Comment: App server is probably a bit much, nginx/apache would be capable of writing an environment variable into a request as well. But you would have to configure/code the "thing" to do that.

Comment: Sorry I should step back, env vars can be applied at Vue build time. So you have a static value of `MANAGER_ADDRESS` stored in your container image. They can't be modified after.

Comment: I'll just write an answer a bit later...

Comment: Thank you @Matt, in case I misunderstand what is static production build, I have added the dockerfile of `browser`.

Comment: A few of the options are in that answer already.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I tried to implement the solution of Hendrik M Halkow, but was a bit confused (sorry for being new to Vue.js).

I don't know where to put `<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>config.js"></script>` and `this.displayURL = config.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL || process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_MyURL `, on my `.vue` file or `.js` file? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224233/discussion-between-ken-tsoi-and-matt).